# Search by numbers of character

Tags: regex, expression

I want search by numbers of character In notepad++ using regular express.

example:

```
Zip code : 85375
Zip code : bs55
Zip code : N14PJ
Zip code : 3977
Zip code : V1y4c2
```

I want a way to search by numbers of character so if I search for Zip code which only has 4 characters/number I want to get this result.

```
Zip code : 3977
Zip code : bs55
```

I hope that I explain this good.

Comment: Search for `Zip code : \w{4}\b`

Comment: Do you want to remove from the file the other zip codes that don't match  ?

Comment: no i just want select them , thank you for help )

Comment: @user3003065 now, that you removed the notepad++ tag, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
^Zip code : .{4}$
```

will serve the purpose

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/bN0rL3

it will select only the required zipcodes. you can see the output in the demo

Comment: One minute to correct the question's formatting, answer and provide an online example, now that's real efficiency :)

Comment: thank you , your code work fine , but could you tell me if i have separator btw info exemple : Zip code : 85375|country : us , in this case what i can do ?

Comment: Try \b instead of $. \b is word boundary.